# maven build executable jar from multiple modules

Tags: java, maven, jar, configuration, pom.xml

i have the following project structure and trying to compile my whole project as a **jar**.

----**parent POM**
----main layer ----services layer ----DTO layer. i'm using **Maven Shade Plugin** to create a unique executable jar file with **mvn package** command but what i get is compilation error like this

```
[INFO] core-data .......................................... FAILURE [  0.616 s]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project core-data: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

\BetRadar\core-data\src\main\java\com\zzilla\entities\sportEntities\Handball.java:[3,46] error: **package com.sportradar.sdk.feed.common.entities** does not exist
[ERROR] \BetRadar\core-data\src\main\java\com\zzilla\entities\sportEntities\Handball.java:[12,12] error: cannot find symbol
```

i put the following build configuration in parent pom. In my main module layer i have a dependency on Services layer project which itself has a dependency on core-data(repository) layer. the package that has mentioned in error log **com.sportradar.sdk.feed.common.entities** exists in sdk jar file which is included in the project structure:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sportradar.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/sdk jar/sdk.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

seems maven has some problem with that dependencies. how can i achieve my expected results to be done? is there a missing part concerning dependency declaration in POM?
        
        MyProjectName

```
        <!-- download source code in Eclipse, best practice -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <source>${source.jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${source.jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>zzilla.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why a system scope dependency? Isn't it just another jar module of your project?

Comment: @Gimby   i changed the system scope dependency and installed that sdk jar file in my local maven repository and added an average dependancy on it. but now i get another error smth like this: Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access http://download.java.net/maven/1 with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy

Comment: So the answer was no, it is not a module of your project but some third party jar. A rather old one setup for Maven 1 I guess.